# Add module Enable/disable functionality in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.2.6

I want to add **`Enable/disable`** functionality in my **`custom module`** by which the module can be enabled or disable directly form **`admin-panel`** for just selecting.

I want to add something like this in my custom module
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Modify this files based on your module (update module namespace)

> Vendor/YourModuleName/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="admin_system_config_changed_section_yourmodulename">
        <observer name="vendor_yourmodulename_disable" instance="Vendor\YourModuleName\Observer\DisableOutput" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Vendor/YourModuleName/Observer/DisableOutput.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\YourModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config;

class DisableOutput implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

const VENDOR_CONFIG = 'yourmodulename/general/enable';

/**
 * @var \Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config
 */
protected $_config;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
 */
protected $_scopeConfig;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;


/**
 * DisableOutput constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config $_config
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $_scopeConfig
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
 */
public function  __construct(
    Config $_config,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $_scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
){
    $this->_config = $_config;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $_scopeConfig;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->request = $request;

}

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $disable = false;
    $scopeType = \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT;
    $scopeCode = 0;

    if($this->request->getParam(\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE))
    {
        $scopeType = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        $scopeCode = $this->storeManager->getStore($this->request->getParam(\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE))->getCode();
    }elseif($this->request->getParam(\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE))
    {
        $scopeType = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE;
        $scopeCode = $this->storeManager->getWebsite($this->request->getParam(\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE))->getCode();
    }
    else
    {
        $scopeType = \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT;
        $scopeCode = 0;
    }
    $moduleConfig= $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::VENDOR_CONFIG, $scopeType);


    if((int)$moduleConfig == 0){
        $disable = true;
    }

    $moduleName = 'Vendor_YourModuleName';
    $outputPath = "advanced/modules_disable_output/$moduleName";

    $this->_config->saveConfig($outputPath,$disable, $scopeType,$scopeCode);
}
}
```

> etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="yourmodulename" translate="label" sortOrder="150" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <resource>Vendor_YourModuleName::configuration</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enable Module</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Enabledisable</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

> etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Vendor_YourModuleName::yourmodulename_configuration"
             title="Configuration"
             resource="Magento_Backend::content"
             module="Vendor_YourModuleName"
             sortOrder="1"
             action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/yourmodulename"
             parent="Vendor_YourModuleName::yourmodulename" />
    </menu>
</config>
```

Comment: Hi @Guxholli Did the above code is worked for you.

Comment: Yes it worked @shivashankarm

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ylgen, i have lot of files in my module, Is there any need to add above functionality for every file.

Comment: @shivashankarm i didnt understand your question . Explain in more details

Comment: nice one but pay attention as this is going to disable the "output" functionalities only. all the others functionalities will work as usual, so the only way is to disable via module:config

Answer (score 2):

This type of functionality does not exist at Magento.

If you want to develop this functionality on your module then you have to add an `If conditions of checking this system configuration field` on every code of this module. That is too complex and too tough to implement this logic on any module code.

Also, Implementation of this system field checking on a module totally depends on the module code and its business logic and how the business logic is implemented  On the code.

Be a developer, my suggestion, you cannot possibly implement this type of enable/disable of a module from admin

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood his question

Comment: Sorry, what is mean of requirement

Answer (score 0):

Create a system Config file in your custom module

You can do like this (Assuming your custom module name is "Sample Shipping"

> Vendor\Module\etc\adminhtml\system.xml
>
> **system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <section id="carriers" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="320" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <group id="sampleShipping" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Sample Shipping</label>
            <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                <label>Enable</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

> Vendor\Module\etc\config.xml
>
> **config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
    <carriers>
        <sampleShipping>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <active>1</active>
            <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
        </sampleShipping>
    </carriers>
</default>
```

Creating those files in your **`custom module`** will enable you to **`disable/enable`** your custom module in
**`Stores > Sales > Shipping method configuration`**

Comment: Thanks For help! Yes Your code creating the option for Enable and disable,  but it seems not working, when I change the status module always remains at same status

Comment: @AkashAgrawal after implementing above code you need to write php code in your class to make sure if module is enabled.