# Custom module enable disable functionality

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5

Hi i have a custom module where am trying to add enable/disable functionality but its not working can anyone suggest me a possible solution am sharing my code below

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="chd" translate="label" sortOrder="150" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <resource>Vendor_Chd::configuration</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enable Module</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Enabledisable</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
   <menu>
       <add id="Vendor_Chd::menu"
           title="Ntz Test Menu" module="Vendor_Chd"
           sortOrder="10"
           resource="Magento_Backend::content"
           />

    <add id="Vendor_Chd::menu_submenu1"
           title="Test sub menu 1" module="Vendor_Chd"
           sortOrder="10" parent="Vendor_Chd::menu"
           action="chd/create/index"
           resource="Vendor_Chd::menu_item"
           />


<!-- settings -->
           <add id="Vendor_Chd::menu_submenusettingsenabledisable"
             title="Settings"
             resource="Magento_Backend::content"
             module="Vendor_Chd"
             sortOrder="1"
             action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/chd"
             parent="Vendor_Chd::menu" />
   </menu>
</config>
```

**Disableoutput.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Chd\Observer;

use Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config;

class DisableOutput implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

const VENDOR_CONFIG = 'chd/general/enable';

/**
 * @var \Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config
 */
protected $_config;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
 */
protected $_scopeConfig;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;


/**
 * DisableOutput constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config $_config
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $_scopeConfig
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
 */
public function  __construct(
    Config $_config,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $_scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
){
    $this->_config = $_config;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $_scopeConfig;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->request = $request;

}

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $disable = false;
    $scopeType = \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT;
    $scopeCode = 0;

    if($this->request->getParam(\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE))
    {
        $scopeType = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        $scopeCode = $this->storeManager->getStore($this->request->getParam(\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE))->getCode();
    }elseif($this->request->getParam(\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE))
    {
        $scopeType = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE;
        $scopeCode = $this->storeManager->getWebsite($this->request->getParam(\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE))->getCode();
    }
    else
    {
        $scopeType = \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT;
        $scopeCode = 0;
    }
    $moduleConfig= $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::VENDOR_CONFIG, $scopeType);


    if((int)$moduleConfig == 0){
        $disable = true;
    }

    $moduleName = 'Vendor_Chd';
    $outputPath = "advanced/modules_disable_output/$moduleName";

    $this->_config->saveConfig($outputPath,$disable, $scopeType,$scopeCode);
}
}
```

**event.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="admin_system_config_changed_section_yourmodulename">
        <observer name="vendor_chd_disable" instance="Vendor\Chd\Observer\DisableOutput" />
    </event>
</config>
```

any advice would be appreciated

Comment: please try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/257856/82670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change below code it will work

```
<field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
    <label>Enabled</label>
    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
</field>
```

In ovserver

```
$scopeType = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
if(!$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('chd/general/active, $scopeType);){
    return $this;
}
```